# Unable to delete a 21 Mb attachment

Tags: attachment, file-storage

I created a 21 Mb attachment to test some code I was writing. Later I saw that my DE org ran out of file storage and it wont let me save any new records (even when the data storage is 40%). I deleted all the attachments there were using the dev console anonymous execute

```
delete [select Id from Attachment];
```

When I went to the Storage Usage page I can still see 1 attachment record left with the 21 Mb size. When I clicked the link Overall Top Files by Storage Utilization, it took me to a page where all the files were listed

[image]

When I click the file name it takes me to a page where it says

[image]

When I run a select query on Attachment in the dev console, it says 0 results. I do not understand why this attachment is not shown in the query and how do I delete it if I cannot even access it.

Thank you.

Comment: awkward! are you able to raise a case to salesforce support?

Comment: I thought if there is a way to delete this without raising a case.

Comment: is the parent record stuck in the organization recycle bin by any chance?

Comment: that is a possibility. however, i am unable to undelete the suspected parent records.

Comment: clear the recyclebin and query with ALL ROWS clause